# How to add a class to the corresponding popup

Tags: jquery

I have got two div's

```
<div id="one">
and
<div id="two">
```

Each div has got a button class named **addonsBtn** , when clicked on that it will open a popup and append data to the corresponding popup

If clicked on First Addon , is it possible to add class by name 'foroneclass' so that it looks this way

```
<div data-role="popup" id="addonsWrap789" class='foroneclass' data-theme="a">
</div>
```

Similarly

If clicked on Second Addon , is it possible to add class by name 'fortwolass' so that it looks this way

```
<div data-role="popup" id="addonsWrap790" class='fortwolass' data-theme="a">
</div>
```

This is my fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/109/

Comment: How are you generating the content of the popup? Clicking the button and generating the popup window won't create a popup with the `div` element already there, so how does that content get generated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. There are a few ways to skin a cat

## Basic solution

Based on your fiddle, you can extend the following two lines:

`Line 8` is:

```
$("#addonsWrap789").popup({history: false}).popup('open').enhanceWithin();
```

Becomes:

```
$("#addonsWrap789").popup({history: false}).popup('open').enhanceWithin().addClass("foroneclassfo");
```

And `line 15`:

```
$("#addonsWrap790").popup({history: false}).popup('open').enhanceWithin();
```

Becomes:

```
$("#addonsWrap790").popup({history: false}).popup('open').enhanceWithin().addClass("foretwoclassfo");
```

## Cleaner solution

I've cleaned up your jsfiddle file a bit. We can approach it in a bit more of a reusable way by taking the `toppname` and appending your desired class suffix onto the end. This way, you could have 2 or 10 modals and it would continue to work as intended.

```
$(document).on('click', '.addonsBtn', function (e) {
  var toppname = $(this).data('toppname');
  var html = '<div class="popup_inner addonsContent"><div class="popup_content"><div class="popup_content_addonsWrap"><div class="addonsListWrap"><h3>Toppings</h3><ul><li><form><div class="ui-checkbox ui-mini"></div></form></li></ul></div></div></div></div>';

  $("#addonsWrap789").html(html).trigger('create').trigger('pagecreate');
  $("#addonsWrap789").trigger('create').trigger('pagecreate');
  $("#addonsWrap789").popup({history: false}).popup('open').enhanceWithin().addClass(toppname + 'class');
});
```

Updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/110/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', '.addonsBtn', function(e) {
    var toppname = $(this).data('toppname');
    var html = '<div class="popup_inner addonsContent"><div class="popup_content"><div class="popup_content_addonsWrap"><div class="addonsListWrap"><h3>Toppings</h3><ul><li><form><div class="ui-checkbox ui-mini"></div></form></li></ul></div></div></div></div>';
    if (toppname === 'forone') {
        $("#addonsWrap789").addClass($(this).attr('data-toppname')+'class');
        $("#addonsWrap789").html(html).trigger('create').trigger('pagecreate');
        $("#addonsWrap789").trigger('create').trigger('pagecreate');
        $("#addonsWrap789").popup({
            history: false
        }).popup('open').enhanceWithin();
    } else if (toppname === 'fortwo') {
        $("#addonsWrap790").addClass($(this).attr('data-toppname')+'class');
        $("#addonsWrap790").html(html).trigger('create').trigger('pagecreate');
        $("#addonsWrap790").trigger('create').trigger('pagecreate');
        $("#addonsWrap790").popup({
            history: false
        }).popup('open').enhanceWithin();
    }
});
```

Highlight this code:

```
$("#addonsWrap789").addClass($(this).attr('data-toppname')+'class');
```

and :

```
$("#addonsWrap790").addClass($(this).attr('data-toppname')+'class');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '.addonsBtn', function(e) {
  var toppname = $(this).data('toppname');
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var html = '<div class="popup_inner addonsContent"><div class="popup_content"><div class="popup_content_addonsWrap"><div class="addonsListWrap"><h3>Toppings</h3><ul><li><form><div class="ui-checkbox ui-mini"></div></form></li></ul></div></div></div></div>';

  $("#" + id ).html(html).trigger('create').trigger('pagecreate');
  $("#" + id ).trigger('create').trigger('pagecreate');
  $("#" + id ).popup({
    history: false
  }).popup('open').enhanceWithin().addClass(toppname);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1Lnb98wh/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.addonsBtn', function(e) {
 var $toppName = $(this).data('toppname'),
     $topClass = $(this).data('topclass'),
     $popup = $("#" + $(this).data("popup")),
     $popupContent = '<div class="popup_inner addonsContent"><div class="popup_content"><div class="popup_content_addonsWrap"><div class="addonsListWrap"><h3>Toppings</h3><ul><li><form><div class="ui-checkbox ui-mini"></div></form></li></ul></div></div></div></div>';

  $($popup).html($popupContent).trigger('create').trigger('pagecreate');
  $($popup).trigger('create').trigger('pagecreate');
  $($popup).popup({
    history: false
  }).popup('open').enhanceWithin().addClass($topClass);

// addClass method will keep the class even when the popup is hidden

});
```

and you can add the Popup Class and Id reference within the Button's data attributes - No need for If statements -

```
 <button class='btn-d addonsBtn' data-toppname="forone" data-topclass="foroneclassfo" data-popup="addonsWrap789" ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all><a data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="ui-link">Addons First Item</a></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i'd suggest a simpler way of doing this. Lets say that you put the desire class name in a attribute of both of your div's.

```
div id="one" key="foroneclass" and div id="two" key="fortwolass"
```

Now when user will click what you can do is pick the value of attribute key.

```
var current_clasname = $(this).attr("key");
```

and then place it it the class name of your popup.

```
$(".pop_up").removeAttr("class"); // To make sure that previous class is removed!!
$(".pop_up").adddClass(current_clasname);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is link of my code you can go through it might be it can help you -

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/114/)

Add these lines in your code

```
JAVASCRIPT Code

$('#addonsWrap789').addClass('foroneclass');
$('#addonsWrap790').addClass('fortwoclass');
```